# How to get a picked file to show in a another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to build a feature where a user will be typing texts then may wanted to add a file, pick an image then the picked image will now be returned at the original text screen with the texts there too. I have develop the feature for inputting the texts [my text feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydnIS.png) then i am stuck at how the picked image will be returned to that same text place. Please how can i get this feature?

Answer (score 0):

First You Need to Add dependencies   `image_picker: ^0.6.4` Used the latest version, Second

pickup an image

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
File _iamge;
Future CameraImage() async{
var iamge =await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  _iamge = iamge;
});
}
```

**Here Is Full Code To know Better Understand.**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
   home: MyHomePage(),
 );
 }
 }
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _iamge;
 Future CameraImage() async{
  var iamge =await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
  _iamge = iamge;
});
 }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 500,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: _iamge==null?Center(child: Text("NO Image 
    Select")):Image.file(_iamge),
      ),
      Divider(),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
            CameraImage();
          },child: Icon(Icons.camera),),
          SizedBox(width: 20,),
          FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},
            child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),),
        ],
        )
      ],
     ),
  );
   }
  }
```

**receive.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/data.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ReceiveData extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final providerdata= Provider.of<Data>(context);

return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: 
     Text(providerdata.value.toString(),style:TextStyle(fontSize:50),),
   ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: I already added the image picker and can pick an image, my question is how can the image picked display/show at the previous screen where the user is typing a text.. Like on facebook share your mind feature, you can select an image and the image will be shown at the place that a user is typing. How is it done?